# VBA Filter everything not in the array

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that filters by everything in an array, however I would like to filter the data by everything not in the array and then delete that information. Any ideas?

```
    Set rng = Sheets("Input Sheet").Range("B" & Srow & ":" & "B" & Frow)
    i = 0
    ReDim ary(0)
    For Each cell In rng
    ary(i) = cell.Value
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve ary(i)
    Next cell
    ws.Range(Startrow_fil & ":" & Endrow_fil).AutoFilter Field:=Fil_Col, Criteria1:="<>" & ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues' here I get a mistype error because of the "&"
    End If
```

The code works perfectly when filtering by the array, in other words, keep everything in the array.

Comment: This is not an answer but you should be able to load the array without the loop if ary is a variant type: `ary = rng.value2`

Comment: Is there a reason you loop and use `ReDim Preserve` to fill this array? Can't you simply do `ary = Sheets("Input Sheet").Range("B" & Srow & ":" & "B" & Frow).Value2`? This doesn't help with your problem, just the first thing I noticed.

Comment: Beat me by 6 seconds @ScottCraner!

Comment: I know, I wrote this code a while ago and since it worked I never had to go back and change it, however I do appreciate your reponse, indeed passing a range to an array is handy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble filtering out rows on one worksheet based on an array with values from another worksheet in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700261/trouble-filtering-out-rows-on-one-worksheet-based-on-an-array-with-values-from-a)