# Unselect Array In Filter

Tags: vba, excel

Help me to unfilter array in sepecific excel, copy and paste in new tab. Unfiltering one item is working well. Run time error occurs while unfiltering more than 3 items in an array. Below is just a sample of my macro.

Macro explanation:

> -> Opening excel
>                      -> Unfilter "COW" from Column A
>                      -> Copy & Paste in new tab named " Unfilter one item"
>                      (Works good)
>                      -> Going back to the first tab
>                      ->Remove old filter
>                      ->Unfilter more than 2 items in column H(Run time error 
>                        occurs)
>                      ->Copy & Paste in new tab named " Unfilter 3 item"

Help to solve this error

```
Sub Unfilter()


    Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\sahana\REPORTS\Delivery Acceptance\2018\Mar\27-03-2018\ORCA Performance Report.xlsb"
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>COW"
        Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Unfilter one item"
        ActiveSheet.Paste



    Windows("ORCA Performance Report.xlsb").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array("<>HR Existing U900", "<>IBC Capacity 2014", "<>IBC 4G Retail Shops"), Operator:=xlFilterOutValues
    Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Unfilter 3 item"
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700261/trouble-filtering-out-rows-on-one-worksheet-based-on-an-array-with-values-from-a

Comment: @ScottCraner the link you have provided is for numbers but i need for words i cannot use 'i = 1 to 5' in my coding since my 'i ' will be   _HR Existing U900, IBC Capacity 2014, IBC 4G Retail Shops_  and so on. Any alternate solution available